# How to change color of a substring of the caption on a button with css3?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have following question. Is it possible to change the color of a substring of the caption of an element with css? For example I have a button, which is captioned "Start". And I want to change the color after hovering the button, of the letters St to white and the color of other letters to black. Is it possible to do so? Hope you can help.

With regards,

Andrej

Comment: Yes it is possible. wrap your text in some span elements and style them ;)

Comment: If you are using an actual `button` element then you can wrap some of the text in a span and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you (it's only an example): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netLveys/)

```
<button>art</button>

button:before {
    content: 'St';
    display: inline;
}
button:hover:before {
    color: red;
}
```